# Referencing a TypeScript type in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

this might be a basic question but maybe my knowledge of c# is misleading me. I'm currently trying to reference a custom type in Typescript and it only allows  it when I actually provide the string value instead of the type reference.  This is what I have:

```
export type MyCustomeType=
    'text1' |
    'text2' |
    'text3';

export class MyCustomeTypeUtils {}
```

In my component I have declared variables of my custom type:

```
var1 : MyCustomeType;
```

The only way I get var1 to have a value is if I do:

```
var1 = 'text1'
```

If I do

```
var1 = MyCustomeType.0
```

or

```
var1 = MyCustomeType.text1
```

it throws an error that it couldn't find the name MyCustomeType.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how it works. This is what TypeScript calls [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string must have. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features together to get enum-like behavior with strings.
>
> ```
> type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
> class UIElement {
>     animate(dx: number, dy: number, easing: Easing) {
>         if (easing === "ease-in") {
>             // ...
>         }
>         else if (easing === "ease-out") {
>         }
>         else if (easing === "ease-in-out") {
>         }
>         else {
>             // error! should not pass null or undefined.
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> let button = new UIElement();
> button.animate(0, 0, "ease-in");
> button.animate(0, 0, "uneasy"); // error: "uneasy" is not allowed here
> ```
>
> You can pass any of the three allowed strings, but any other string will give the error
>
> Argument of type '"uneasy"' is not assignable to parameter of type `'"ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out"'`

**Note:** If you want to use real enums [TypeScript supports that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Comment: So in order to assign a value to one of these types I have to give it only one of the allowed string instead of how enums are used?  Maybe I was confusing the two :)

Answer (score 0):

I fell into a similar trap. What you can do is on your utils class create a static that returns a type of `MyCustomType` with the string `text1`.

```
public static readonly Text1:MyCustomType = 'text1';
```

Then you can do

```
let myVar:MyCustomType = UtilClass.Text1;
```

Comment: Thank you Dan!   However this approach didn't work for me :(

Comment: @eagleEye sorry, had my C# hat on. Does my change to the static help?

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry didn't see your message until now, I hear you I mix languages all the time :D.  I'll try and let you know.